# Replace substring randomly Python

Tags: python, string, random

> I'm trying to replace every occurence of an int literal with a random
> generated value. But for each "int" it gets generates towards the same
> value for each location. How can I change each location randomly?

```
if '"int"' in addstr3:              
 randint = random.randint(0, 100)                   
 addstr4 = addstr3.replace('"int"', str(randint))              
   else:                 
 addstr4 = addstr3
```

A sample input would be a string as "int" "int" "int" and the output would be 94 94 94

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please [edit] your question to make a [mcve] including sample input and current and expected output so that we can better understand your question

Comment: You set `randint` once and then use it in a `replace()`, which  does multiple replacements.  Thus you get the same replacement number multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to take advantage of the `count` parameter of the `replace()` function

```
addstr3='"int" "int" "int"'

while "int" in addstr3:
    addstr3=addstr3.replace('"int"',str(randint(0,100)),1)
    print(addstr3)

9 "int" "int"
9 29 "int"
9 29 57
```